# Обновление значений параметров на аднроид устройстве через bluetooth

Tags: android, ui, android-service, android-bluetooth

Здравствуйте,

в приложении, которое я сейчас разрабатываю в режиме реального времени идет обмен информацией по bluetooth (через bluetooth Service ) который обменивается данными с основным активити следующим образом:

```
// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if (D)
                    Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to,
                            mConnectedDeviceName));
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                Toast.makeText(BluetoothChat.this,writeMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//              mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);

                // My changes
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < writeBuf.length;i++){
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add( ( Integer.toHexString( (int) writeBuf[i] & 255 ) )  );
                }
                //========================

                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                for (int i = 0; i <=msg.arg1 ; i++){
                    Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE_READ, ReadBuf[" + i + "]: " + Integer.toHexString( (int) readBuf[i] & 255) );
                }

                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

//              mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  "
//                      + readMessage);

                //My chnages
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName);
                for (int i = 0; i < readBuf.length;i++){
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add( ( Integer.toHexString( (int) readBuf[i] & 255 ) )  );
                    if (readBuf[i] == 0 && i > 80)
                        break;
                }
                //=====================

                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

В активити имеются параметры значения которых постоянно обновляются.
Сначала через буфер **writeBuf** я отправляю запрос, потом мне приходится от другого устройства ждать ответ в **readBuf**. 
Проблема в том что в readBuf, значения приходят асинхронно. И приходиться проверять по содержанию сообщения для какого параметра пришел ответ. 
Иногда сообщение приходит поврежденным, приходиться еще раз отправлять данное сообщение.

Пока у меня следующий алгоритм работы программы:

1) Отправляю запрос для параметра_1
2) Жду некоторое время
3) Проверяю ответ пришел для параметра_1 ?
            -Да:  не повреждено ли сообщение ?
             ----Да(повреждено): -> (возврат) 1)
             ----Нет(не повреждено): берем данные и на выход
        -Нет: -> (возврат к) 1)

Цикл 1)-3) повторяется 10 раз и затем выходит. Т.е. параметр не обновился
все 10 раз либо приходило сообщение ни для этого параметра, либо оно 
было повреждено.

Беда в том что проверка проводиться в UI потоке и когда параметров много 
приложение начинает зависать.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно организовать чтение данных 
по bluetooth, чтобы приложение не тормозило при чтении и проверке данных (пришедших с другого устройства) ?

Большое спасибо за ответы.

Добавил некоторую часть кода сервисного класса, который занимается приемом и передачей сообщений:

`public class BluetoothChatService {`

................................

```
/**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * 
     * @param out
     *            The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
                return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }


/**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device. It handles all
     * incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes,
                            -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * 
         * @param buffer
         *            The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1,
                        buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

`}`

В UI потоке отправка сообщения выглядит:

`mChatService.write(message);`

Comment: Обрабатывайте все в сервисе (в отдельном потоке). и зачем вы гоняете сырые (byte[]) данные? обработайте, проверьте, а в активити уже присылайте готовые проверенные.

Comment: @ Yura Ivanov, спасибо большое за отклик. Действительно, хорошая идея проверять на ошибке все в сервисе. Надо будет попробовать. А что вы думаете по поводу асинхронного обмена, как его лучше организовать, чтобы не приходилось ждать ответа ? У меня пока есть идея организовать буфер в виде массива (возможно многомерного) и по приходу ответа туда все складывать. А когда нужно, по запросу брать из буфера данные.

Comment: В принципе идея с обменом через handler нормальная. В качестве буфера можно использовать базу, например. При отправке в кладете в базу сообщение, когда получите в сервисе ответ для этого сообщения, ставите галку отправлено, оповещаете activity через handler, она опрашивает базу, обновляет адаптер... Аналогично с пришедшими данным - оповещаете activity и одновременно кладете в базу. Так сообщения не потеряются (после 10 попыток) и асинхронность будет и activity не будет подвешиваться.

Comment: @ Yura Ivanov, спасибо за ответ. Идея хорошая но на практике у меня возникли некоторые проблемы. В частности: к примеру выполняется UI поток, он обновляет графику, используя базу, а также отправляет, к примеру, 3 сообщения. Пока UI еще что-то делает, от другого устройства приходит ответ на эти 3 сообщения. Проблема теперь в том, что Handler (который я приводил выше) обрабатывает пришедшие 3 сообщения (срабатывание **MESSAGE_READ**) только когда UI поток закончит свою работу, т.е. **Handler** получается работает не параллельно UI потоку а последовательно.

Comment: Хотя вроде как сервисные функции должны работать параллельно, то и Handler должен работать параллельно. Но этого не происходит. В результате 1-2 сообщения из этих 3 не приходят и параметры на экране андроид устройства остаются пустыми. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы Handler работал параллельно UI потоку ?   Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Добавил небольшой кусок кода по реализации сервисной функции обработки сообщений по bluetooth.

Comment: Вы перезатираете buffer при каждом чтении и фактически три раза отправляете одно и то же сообщение. Как я выше писал, обработайте сообщение, в хэндлер передавайте уже готовые данные. Да, в UI потоке один цикл сообщений и хэндлер принимает сообщения именно в этом цикле, все работает последовательно, так и должно быть.

Comment: @ Yura Ivanov, спасибо большое. Кажется я начинаю понимать суть. Другое устройство (не андроид) должно отвечать на каждое сообщение. Тогда если я отправляю 3 сообщения с андроид на не андроид, то и обратно придет 3 сообщения. Но они могут быть разорванными (это я выяснил в ходе изучения программы), т.е. часть первого сообщения может перейти во второе (может и не перейти), часть 2го в 3ье сообщение.

Comment: Получается в результате если я отправляю с андроид устройства 3 сообщения. То нужно ждать пока эти 3 сообщения придут и после этого склеивать их, если нужно, в одно целое и потом выдирать каждое сообщение в отдельности и класть базу

Comment: @ Yura Ivanov, из вашего ответ ни совсем понял почему вы считате, что **buffer** я отправляю 3 раза одно и то же. У меня на практике было так, отправляю я 3 сообщения (запрос на 3 параметры). Параметры содержат следующие массивы 1 - 1,2,3,4; 2 - 7,8,9,10;              3 - 12,13,14,15. Приходят ответы 3 сообщения: 1 - 1, 2, 3; 2 - 4,7, 8, 9; 3 - 10,  12, 13, 14, 15; (т.е. сообщения пришли разорванными) . Получается при каждом чтении **buffer** имеет разное содержание. Т.е. в первом сообщении: 1, 2, 3. Во втором: 4,7, 8, 9. В третьем: 10,  12, 13, 14, 15.